# Ruby on Rails, will_paginate, check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate to list a huge ammont of files in different pages. I also have a check_box in order to choose files for the futher analysis.

controller:

```
@files = FileDB.search(search_string).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

view:

```
  <button type="button" id="check_all">Check/Uncheck all</button>
 <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'analyse' do %>Analyse<% end %>

    <% @filess.each do |file| %>
    <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td><%= file.name %></p>
    lala...
```

My problem is that I can choose the files which are situated in one page.So by clicking on "check/uncheck all" it checks not all available files, but files of this specific page. I would like to be able to check different files from different pages together.

Example: 10 files on the page 1, 4 files on the page 2. I want to check 5 files from page one and all files from page 2 and then by clicking on the buttom "Analyse", those 9 files have to be analyzed together, so the checkbox should remember different files from different pages

Thanks in advance

***edit*** according to the solution of juanpastas

view:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>    
 // see note below
sessionStorage.fileIds = ' ';

// this way:
// 1. you execute the function appending just one handler
// 2. you can change content of .checkboxes-container with AJAX to do pagination

$('.checkboxes-container').on('change', ':checkbox', function(){
  // search for "space id space", examples: " 1 " or " 10 "
  var id = new RegExp(' ' + this.value + ' ');

  // get that part of the string
  var match = (sessionStorage.fileIds.match(id) || [])[0];

  // toggle value, this is: replicate check box behaviour in this variable
  // ids will be saved as " 1 2 3 10 15 ", spaces in both sides to eliminate special cases.
  if(match) sessionStorage.fileIds = sessionStorage.fileIds.replace(id, ' ');

  else sessionStorage.fileIds = sessionStorage.fileIds + this.value + ' ';

})
</script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>   
$('[name=analyse]').click(function(){
  // " 1 2 3 10 " is sent as [1,2,3,10]
  var fileIds = sessionStorage.ids.split(',').filter(function(e){if(e[0]) return e;})

  // change url, check server is receiving an array.
  $.get('/files', { file_ids: fileIds });
})
</script>
                    <%= form_for Group.new, url: what_to_do_files_path ,method: :get ,:validate => true do |f| %>


                    <div class="field">
                    <%=f.text_field :group_name, placeholder: "Group Name" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>

                    <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'analyse' do %>Analyse;<% end %>
                    <button type="button" id="check_all" class="btn"> Check/Uncheck all</button>

                        <% @files.each do |file| %>
                        <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id , false %></td>file.name</p>




                        <%end%>

                  <%end%>
```

controller:

```
what_to_do
    a = params[:file_ids].split(',')
end
```

It shows me an error, that there is not split-function for Nil cless, so params[:file_ids] is empty, though I checked the check_boxes

Answer (score 1):

You need to save selected items somehow, for example in session(client or server) or a hidden input.

This is saving in browser session:

```
// see note below
sessionStorage.fileIds = ' ';

// this way:
// 1. you execute the function appending just one handler
// 2. you can change content of .checkboxes-container with AJAX to do pagination

$('.checkboxes-container').on('change', ':checkbox', function(){
  // search for "space id space", examples: " 1 " or " 10 "
  var id = new RegExp(' ' + this.value + ' ');

  // get that part of the string
  var match = (sessionStorage.fileIds.match(id) || [])[0];

  // toggle value, this is: replicate check box behaviour in this variable
  // ids will be saved as " 1 2 3 10 15 ", spaces in both sides to eliminate special cases.
  if(match) sessionStorage.fileIds = sessionStorage.fileIds.replace(id, ' ');

  else sessionStorage.fileIds = sessionStorage.fileIds + this.value + ' ';

})
```

Then, when analyse is clicked you can send all of those ids:

```
$('[name=analyse]').click(function(){
  // " 1 2 3 10 " is sent as [1,2,3,10]
  var fileIds = sessionStorage.ids.split(',').filter(function(e){if(e[0]) return e;})

  // change url, check server is receiving an array.
  $.get('/files', { file_ids: fileIds });
})
```

Check [this](http://jsbin.com/ozayoy/2/edit).

In controller:

```
before_filter :make_array_from_file_ids


def make_array_from_file_ids
  # this depends on the name you used in AJAX call
  params[:file_ids] = params[:file_ids].split ','
end
```

**Note** I am not sure if you need this in controller. Maybe not. Maybe you need something different.

Comment: It is not a problem if by reloading the ids would be lost

Comment: I find this start useful, so you can complete =)

Comment: See that this way ids won't be lost. And it's much simpler.

Comment: I edited my question, so you can see that I "copied $ pasted" your solution into my code. Unfortunately I get an error that there is not split-function for nil. so params[:file_ids] is empty

Comment: what params are you receiving? what params are you sending? you know where to look?

Comment: According to your solution I am sending :file_ids and I should receive it as well.But in reality I am sending following:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "group"=>{"group_name"=>"uuuu"
 "analyze"=>"",
 "files"=>["93"]} So, i am not sending :file_ids, so i do not know what goes wrong there

Comment: seems you code is not working with `  $.get('/files', { file_ids: fileIds });` instead of that you should be submitting a form. If your button is inside a for I think you could use `$('[name=analyse]').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault();`

Comment: a html code is above under edit. there is a form_for, and your code ruins my client side validation somehow: <%= form_for Group.new, url: what_to_do_files_path ,method: :get ,:validate => true do |f| %>

Comment: you have to run javascript after content is loaded.

Comment: I pasted two javascripts just after the whole stuff in edit/view and it is still not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34773/discussion-between-katja-and-juanpastas)

Answer (score 0):

for that you can choose "turbolink gem" in rails 3 because when you select some file in page 1 and some other files in page 2 , all are become group together and after that you can analyzed.

```
gem 'turbolinks'
```

and after that need to small change in controller. 
visit:- http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks

Comment: small change in a controller? In railscasts they do nothing with a controller, only javascript

Comment: yes, but very help full for these kind of queries and ajax response.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea how to change my controller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check some checkboxes and on submit button, you want to do some analyzing stuff, Then I will suggest you to Build a form first. Checkboxes can't remember the files from different pages, you have to put these checkboxes into a form.